# optimization with postgres cursor in php

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel-5

I'm dealing with big volumes of data. It's a huge table where I'm performing unions through a SQL statement, from my php, and sending over to my own localhost db. I've got the thing sorted out but I want to optimize this. It had to stay overnight merging around 83.000 rows.

```
    $con = new PDO("pgsql:host, port,dbname, user, password");
    $con->beginTransaction(); // cursors require a transaction.
    $stmt = $con->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
    $innerStatement = $con->prepare("FETCH 1 FROM cursor1");
    while($innerStatement->execute() && $row = $innerStatement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        insertDataToDB($row);
    }
```

Question: will changing the line to "FETCH 1000 FROM cursor1" make it so that I'm fetching 1000 rows each time instead of one? Will that help performance?
I'm hoping this larger operation was a one time thing. But in future I will have to move smaller amounts of data... still the query is rather heavy since it relies in comparisons with timestamps, otherwise how would I know if my DB is updated or not?

Thank you.

Comment: If you have to move some data from a server to another one(if I understood right) you can dump the db, import to your localhost, and perform local queries,that are faster.

Comment: This time it was a one time thing because of the volume of data. From now on I need to keep both DB's in sync. Meaning I need to move only the new rows (which may still be a lot) every day

Comment: 83000 rows, could be inserted in very few seconds. Also the queries requires not so much time. When I listened queries that took lot times where benchmarks for comparison with graph db that involves 1M rows joined them selves 6 times. With 1M^ 6 joins to perform the RDBMS get in trouble. Or hard recursive queries. But also, I tested a GetPath for a tree with 10000 items, around 100k recursive queries, took me 14 sec.But 83000 rows? I would think to indexes, may be you have to index something.  I would purpose a trigger, that concatenate the SQL instruction of relative operation and insert into

Comment: Continue: A table. So you divide the job along the day. When you have to update, select all from the table and run a fast execution

Comment: If it's about keeping the DBs in sync you might want to check out replication. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling

Comment: DB's are identical but not exactly the same. I'm joining some of the elements.

Comment: What you are calling "DBs" are probably tables within the same database? (the fragment in your question has only one connection)